# WordPress Plugin "Search and Filter" - display Custom Post Type Categories in results.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am manipulating the results.php file from the Search and Filter Pro plugin (WordPress). I'm trying to also display the categories for each of those Custom Post types. But all I'm seeing on the front end is "Array" instead of the category names. Here is my current code:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    ?>

<div class="pagination">
    
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
    <?php
        /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
        if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
        {
            echo "<br />";
            wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
        }
    ?>
</div>

<?php

while ($query->have_posts())
{
    $query->the_post();
    
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $post_category = get_the_category();
    $description = get_field('product_description', $post_id);
    
    ?>

    <div class="product-div">
        
        <?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                echo '<p>';
        ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail("small");?>
        <?php
                echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
        <h3><?php echo $post_category; ?></h3>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php echo $description;?>

        
    </div>
    
    <?php
    }
    ?>

   <?php
   }
   else
  {
   echo "No Results Found";
   }
  ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the function `get_the_category` returns an array of WP_Term objects as per the [reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/). Try `<?php echo $post_category[0]->name; ?>` or if the post has more than one category assigned you can loop through like:

```
foreach($post_category as $category){
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!!